# Integrate mockito logic with the production code

Tags: java, mockito, httpurlconnection

Below is a simple java command line utility to download a web page into a file.

This code was brought from here:

https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/java-urlconnection-and-httpurlconnection-examples

My question: is it a good idea to integrate mockito with this command line program?

For example, I want to extend the features of this utility to return an internal server error response code even if the provided url is working.

The use case is that the developed component needs to be deployed into a production-like running instance on a staging server where it's not possible to install a tool like Mockoon. Also, it is not enough to depend on the developed tests using JUnit and Mockito. This is because in this case we will be running integration tests where the running instance has all the dependencies and other systems can interface with the component. When the component is functional in such an environment, I need to see how it will behave when the url returns an internal server error for example.

We can achieve the same using [Mockoon](https://mockoon.com/), but, since Mockoon cannot be installed due to policy restrictions, I wanted to find out if there is an alternative by coding the mocking logic along with the developed component.

My thoughts on this approach in the case of the command line utility below, we can add another argument to configure the utility to mock the `httpurlconnection` to return an internal server error even if the url is working without problems.

The code of the command line utility:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class DownloadWebPage {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Syntax: <url> <file>");
            return;
        }
 
        String url = args[0];
        String filePath = args[1];
 
        try {
 
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            URLConnection urlCon = urlObj.openConnection();
 
            InputStream inputStream = urlCon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
 
            BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
 
            while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
 
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
 
            System.out.println("Web page saved");
 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("The specified URL is malformed: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An I/O error occurs: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a rough modified version of the above code to achieve what I am looking for:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class DownloadWebPage {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Syntax: <url> <file>");
            return;
        }
 
        String url = args[0];
        String filePath = args[1];
        String mockFlag = args[2];
 
        try {
 
            URL urlObj;
            URLConnection urlCon;

            if (mockFlag.equals("interal_server_error") {
                //Set up the mocks for urlObj and urlCon
                //Must return the response code Internal Server Error
                ...
                ...
            } else {
                urlObj = new URL(url);
                urlCon = urlObj.openConnection();
            }
 
            InputStream inputStream = urlCon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
 
            BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
 
            while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
 
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
 
            System.out.println("Web page saved");
 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("The specified URL is malformed: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An I/O error occurs: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the first problem we are introducing is readability issues. We can resolve such issues by using the Strategy software design pattern. I wanted to know if this approach is reasonable and if anyone used it before.

Comment: Could you present a piece of code (even pseudocode) which will  show what you want to achieve? Or how would you like to change your existing code? Mockito is not intended for production code. In order to handle unexpected scenarios you need to handle those explicitly.

Comment: Mockito is for testing only. Do not use it in production code

Comment: maybe you would consider `wiremock` instead. You can configure it using some json files or programmatically, take a look here:  https://wiremock.org/

Comment: @fascynacja I updated the question with more details to clarify my use-case and the possible change to be made to the command line utility.

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir I will check it out `wiremock`.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect `wiremock` scenario. You can run wiremock as part of your code uising feature toggle, part of a test instance or as standalone server. Place static or dynamic mappings and lets go. I am always doing it like: searing ID=200 returns OK, searching id=404 return not found, .... like this you will always know what was expected and if your app woirks correct. 
Often you will hear internal mocking with switches is better - for a first appraoch maybe BUT you will have toggles and test code on real prod code + it is not integrative - just mocked instead. So wiremock should fit.

Comment: @LenglBoy thanks a lot... would you be able to add an answer with a sample code?

Comment: Your stated use case is integration testing. It's not a great idea to be mocking the behaviour of another module inside the module under test given the point of it is to test how modules work together. But it is a reasonable idea to have a mocked version of other modules so that you can perform layered integration testing. Once you get to system testing of course there should be no mocking at all.

Comment: Integration testing is happening on a server that has no internet connectivity that's why I need to find a mocking solution.